# Xamarin Essentials Save Object Details

Tags: .net, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.essentials

I'm looking for a good way to save a list of details into Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.

Basically something like

```
<Item>
    <Name>Toast</Name>
    <Weight>0.5oz</Weight>
    <Quantity>4</Quantity>
</Item>
```

I thought of doing some xml serialization but I'm not sure that's the best approach.

This list will be less than 500 items, with as many as 6 attributes per item, Name, Weight, Quantity, ImageRefPath, etc.

Anyone have any suggestions and/or examples of a good way to store this?

Things that won't exist in the Items collection are:

No binary data.
No Images.
No BLOBS.

Comment: use SQLite.  This is not what Preferences was designed for

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having a dependency like SQL lite for a small application...

Comment: then just serialize it to a file

Comment: @Jason, I was looking into that yesterday and this morning.  Apparently serialization has issues on IOS due to limitations on reflection?  Sooo...  that's where I'm at in this process now.  Finding reliable serialization mechanisms.

Comment: I've used Newtonsoft in iOS projects for years without any issues.  I'd suggest actually trying it out and seeing if you have any problems instead of worrying about theoretical issues that may occur.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to convert the items to a json string.Then save it to  Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.

For example,define a model first:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Weight{ get; set; }
    public string Quantity{get;set;}
    public string ImageRefPath{get;set;}
    ...
}

//convert the items data to json string and save
ObservableCollection<MyItem> ItemList;
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ItemList);
Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Set("list", json);

//get the json string then convert to the List<MyItem>.
string json = Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get("list","");
ObservableCollection<MyItem> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<MyItem>>(json );
```

Comment: I was very much considering something like this.  However the more I started to dig into JSON Serialization, or apparently any serialization, IOS has some limitations on reflection tasks.  So apparently serialization on IOS doesn't work?  Looking for other options that are cross platform stable.

Comment: I don't have any problems with ios.It works for me.You could have a try.